# Find a coordinate along a path

Tags: trigonometry, angle, rectangles, curve, ellipse

My trigonometry needs a little help.

How would I go about calculating the point of the nearest possible intersection with a line along a rounded corner?

Take this image:

[image: example]

What I would like to know is, given that I know **point a**, and the dimensions of the rectangle, how would I find **point b** when the edges of the rectangle are curved?

So far, as you can see, I've only managed to calculate the nearest edge of the rectangle as if it had right-angled corners.

If it matters, I'm doing this in ActionScript 3. But example sudo-code will suffice.

Comment: If ActionScript supports first class paths, consider creating two paths and calling an intersection routine. That will often be easier than creating explicit formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the vector from the midpoint `M` of the corner to `A`:

`v_x = a_x - m_x`

`v_y = a_y - m_y`

then go radius of the corner `r` times towards `A` to get to the intersection point `I`

`i_x = m_x + r*v_x`

`i_y = m_y + r*v_y`

This obviously only works if the nearest intersection is on the rounded corner. Just calculate the other intersections with the edges, too, and then check which has the nearest distance to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the radius `R` of the circle that generates the round corner and the coordinates `(Xr,Yr)` of the point where the two sides of a non rounded rectangle cross each other.

Then the coordinates for the center of the circle that generates the round corner are `(Xc, Yc) = (Xr-R, Yr-R)`

From here, it's a matter of solving the equation of the cross point between the segment line defined by point `A=(Xa, Ya)` and point `(Xc, Yc)`, whose parametric equation is:

```
x = Xa + p*(Xc-Xa)
y = Ya + p*(Yc-Ya)
```

and the circle whose equation is

```
(x-Xc)^2 + (y-Yc)^2 = R^2
```

Substitute values for `x` and `y` from the parametric euation of the line in the equation of the circle, and you will have an equation with only one unkown: `p`. Solve the equation, and if there are more than one solution, choose the one that is in the range `[0,1]`. Substitute the found value of `p` in the parametric equation of the line to get the point of intersection.

Graphically:

[image: Rounded rect intersection]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the radius and center of the corner as R and C=(Xc, Yc), then the nearest point on the corner to the given point A=(Xa, Ya) is the intersection point of the corner and the line defined by the given point and the center. This point can be directly expressed as

X = Xc + R*(Xa-Xc)/|AC|  
Y = Yc + R*(Ya-Yc)/|AC|

where |AC| = Sqrt((Xa-Xc)^2 + (Ya-Yc)^2)